# Is there a viewcontroller to make current photo or image a wallpaper using the standard Action?

Tags: iphone, view, controller, wallpaper

I've spend an inordinate amount of time searching for a view-controller that will bring up the UIActionSheet to make the current picture the wallpaper (similar to the one used to send an image *in* an email: MFMessageComposeViewController).  I noticed that in the developer.apple.com iOS library documentation not a single doc comes up if I just type the word "wallpaper"  Furthermore, I've read that there are no Apple-approve methods of setting the lock-screen, for example, programmatically.... But I thought that there would be an ActionSheet delegate that would allow us to make a photo in an App, other than Settings and Photos (or Camera), a wallpaper-- in my case I want to make it the Lock-screen.

There are methods to mail the photo, print it, and MMS (I think), but is there just no "approved" way to go into the "Use as Wallpaper" action sheet dialog from apps other that Apple apps?  Leaving us with the option of just telling the use to navigate out of the current app and use either Settings or Photos (if we save the current photo to the Camera Roll or Photo Library) ...

What say you?  Any leads or hints on how to accomplish this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such kind of functionality available in iOS SDK. You need to save photo in photo album then from only default photos application a user can set a photo as wallpaper.